# Small installed footprint Linux distro with X and Browser

Tags: linux, vmware

I'm looking for a modern Linux distro that can be installed on a very small VM image (2GB or less, prefer 1GB) that contains X-Windows and enough to run browser (like Firefox). I thought this topic is very common but I could not find a good match.

I tried Ubuntu Mini and just installing Lubuntu Minimum costs me 3+ GB. Many small distros that comes in a small .iso ended up with a large installation. I feel that I needed one that uses compress volume. Also, I think the swap is going to be a problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, voted to close because this is a software recommendation and out of scope for SU.

Answer (score 1):

[Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org) or one of it's [variants](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/PuppyVersion) is a fully capable Linux distro, it will install 100MB of disk space, 256MB if you want OpenOffice as well. It runs from a RAM disk and can exist in a vMachine with 256MB RAM and 512MB disk allocated to it quite nicely.

You may also want to review other [lightweight Linux distros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Linux_distribution), there are quite a few that could fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

try http://tinycorelinux.net/
it will require a little effort to install
or you can go with a minimal arch linux installation if you don't mind a lot of extra work

Answer (score 0):

**Just run live from the ISO**, Linux Mint, any Ubuntu, Debian, just about all the live ISO's are still under 2GB, and I get to run a basically full Linux from a tiny 2GB memory card or USB device.

You do need enough RAM for your files & tmp, but if your requirements are low you might still be able to get away with only 1GB ram, but 4GB would be luxurious. I'm using under 5GB of ram right now, after installing Chromium (you can install things OK too) and running it + 2 separate ram-hungry Firefox profiles.

-> The 5GB of RAM used includes about 1.2GB taken up by copying the whole live ISO to ram (with the `toram` boot option) so that any "system reads" have a speed of about 1-2GB/sec with access times 0.03ms. Starting any program takes a few seconds at the most.

Setting it up involves copying files & installing packages after boot, and if you want to save files, mount & write to a separate (non-ram) partition (linking your home to there should work).

There are ways to create your own live ISO from a "test system", they're generally rather involved and a web search about your desired distro would be more fruitful.

---

To search distros, use the DistroWatch.com search https://distrowatch.com/search.php and you can browse categories like "Old Computers", "Live Medium" (almost all run live), "Netbooks" or maybe "Thin Client" may be what you're looking for.